# Web Scraping Python, Extraer contenido de script

Tags: javascript, python, scraping

Tengo un problema con este pequeño codigo, Estoy intentando extraer lo que se encuentra dentro de aquel script, Pero no se me ocurre una forma de declarar la busqueda. Dejo el código.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = 'https://tioanime.com/ver/shin-sakura-taisen-the-animation-7'
page = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

eq = soup.find_all('var')
print(eq.text)
```

Al momento de extraer toda la estructura, Si me da obviamente lo que quiero extraer pero no se como especificarlo. Dejo imagen de aquella parte que intento extraer.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que yo sepa BS4 no puede parsear etiquetas `<string>`, lo que si puedes hacer es buscar el texto con una expresión regular:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


urls = 'https://tioanime.com/ver/shin-sakura-taisen-the-animation-7'
page = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

patt = re.compile(r'var videos = \[.*\];')
var = soup.find(text=patt)
print(var.string)
```

Salida:

> ```
> var videos = [["Prime","https:\/\/v.tioanime.com\/embed.php?s=prime&v=ZFJVRUM0eDFoaDBRTWJPWWU2R2w0ZDZWYkcvWWw4M3FzRTlyWVBZanhMSmtQelpOd2Nja1NnNXA4SzZrdkRZU2xWWTFjaWpEeWptTCtDUG5OcmFXSVE9PQ==",0],["Fembed","https:\/\/www.fembed.com\/v\/rg5lnheee0-m7l-",0],["Mega","https:\/\/mega.nz\/embed#!m8EiBATS!vGr1yPVdJ1L0SEYT1mC1HpB05SdDFZ3nctQjqWJafcY",0],["Okru","https:\/\/ok.ru\/videoembed\/1828282239567",0],["YourUpload","https:\/\/www.yourupload.com\/embed\/Uq36fR5x4RI2",0],["Maru","https:\/\/my.mail.ru\/video\/embed\/9149163570439654825#tioanime#3497",0],["Netu","https:\/\/hqq.tv\/player\/embed_player.php?vid=NFhLVmpQNnZ2L2hkNUdOV2tjLzRYZz09",0]];
>
> $(document).ready(function () {
>     initEpisode();
> });
> ```